# Why is it given that an odd polynomial can be written in the form $ax^3 +bx$?

Tags: polynomials

So a question give that P(x) is an odd polynomial of degree three. So now I know that $P(x) = ax^3 + bx^2
 +cx +d $. And $P(-x) = -P(x) $since it is odd. However, the solutions say that given this informations, it can actually be written simply in the form $ax^3 +bx$. Why is this so?

Comment: do you mean $bx^2$ or $b^2$ when you define $P(x)$?

Comment: $P(-x)$ and $-P(x)$ are polynomials. If they are equal they must have the same coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For odd polynomial $P(x)$, we have
$P(x)+P(-x)=0$ for all real values of $x$, so if $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, then
we get $$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d-ax^3+bx^2-cx+d=0 \implies 2bx^2+2d=0=0x^2+0,$$ for all  real values of $x$. This implies $b=0=d$. So finally we have $P(x)=ax^3+cx$

Comment: Thanks, I see. The equation P(x) + P(-x) = 0 is really insightful, I've never thought of it that way before

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Actually, why does it imply that b = 0 = d???

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh I think I know. It is because only the distinct zero polynomial can be P(x) = 0

Comment: When $bx^2+d=0 \implies x^2=-d/b$, bu this is called root(s). But if $bx^2+d=0$ for all real values of $x$ the $bx^2+d=0x^2+0$. Namely, coefficient of each powers of  $x$ have to be zero. For instance if $px^2+qx+r=0, \forall x\in R$, this means $p=q=r=0$. But if it is an equation then $x={-q\pm\sqrt{q^2-4pr}}{2P}.$. I have edited my answer slightly for this point for you.

Answer (score 3):

The equation $P(-x)=-P(x)$ says that the polynomial $P(x)$ is pointsymmetric to the origin.

If you plug in, $P(-x)= -ax^3+bx^2-cx+d$ and $-P(x)=-ax^3-bx^2-cx-d$. Then the equation gives $P(x) = ax^3+cx$.

Comment: Ok I see. It would be vice versa for an even polynomial too right?

Comment: Also what did you do? Did you just equate the parts which are equal and discard the parts that are not?

Comment: Just equating both sides and discarding the terms that don't fit.